Hometech Alfa 7LM Plus bootloop error and can't access via adb/fastboot
My device is Hometech Alfa 7LM Plus. I made a mistake while rooting my device and now I can't boot it.
I tried rooting my device, but TWRP did not support it, so I tried rooting without TWRP.
I downloaded my device's stock ROM (not sure if it was safe or the right ROM, just the label was true) and copied boot.img (I don't remember the device's CPU model, so I am not sure I must copy boot.img or recovery.img or anything else) file to the device.
Then I patched the stock ROM with Magisk in the device itself and flashed to the device patched_boot.img with fastboot. It flashed, but now I can't boot my device nor access recovery with power + volume keys or adb/fastboot (even if they don't connect or list the device).
How can I fix that situation?

Your device is uses a MediaTek CPU. MediaTek uses special flash tools for Windows (that have leaked so you can download it on certain sites) that usually can flash a device when it is in shut down state (really weird). That would be a way to recover your device, however you would still need the factory image in the format for the flash tool.

I have stock ROM for device. When I execute neofetch on termux in device, it return "Armv7" as CPU, are you sure about MediaTek (I don't know very info about hardware, sorry.) Anyway, can you say name of that flash tool please? Thanks for help.

Armv7 is a CPU architecture, not a CPU manufacturer. Armv7 is like getting "x86" on a PC that runs Intel or AMD CPU.

Oh, my bad. Thanks for info. Does that tool you said is "MTK Flash Tool"?
